# Custom NSCursor is being reset when subviews are added to a view in the window

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, appkit, nscursor

I'm using `NSTrackingArea` to define 2 areas in a `NSView` subclass. Then I'm using mouseEntered/mouseExited to change the cursor to a custom one.

So all works fine when the mouse enters the top tracking area and the custom cursor gets set as expected. All still good when I mouseDown and drag on the top tracking area. But I have another part of the UI that updates when the mouse is dragged and it adds subviews to a view elsewhere on the same window.

As soon as the first subview is added elsewhere, my custom cursor disappears and it reverts back to the arrow cursor. I thought I might be able to force the cursor back to the custom one using `cursorUpdate` for my view but for some reason it never gets called, even when set as an option in the `NSTrackingArea`.

Am a bit stumped with this one...

Comment: Cocoa event handling guide tells "As with any other kind of NSTrackingArea object, you might occasionally need to recompute and recreate a tracking-area object used for cursor updates when the associated view has changes in its location or size. See “Managing a Tracking-Area Object” for more information." have you considered this?

Comment: The tracking areas were still valid and the view hadn't changed either location or size in this instance. Have added my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by overriding `cursorUpdate` in the window's custom contentView. An empty `cursorUpdate` method stopped the update from getting passed up the chain and the custom cursor now remains as I've set it.

Comment: Just to be safe, if your window is resizable, you should check that it still shows the resize cursors when the cursor is at the edge. I don't know that you solution will break it, but it's worth checking.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I didn't say that the custom cursor is only being set when the user is in a specific mode, which has a matching BOOL. In cursorUpdate if they are not in this mode, then [super cursorUpdate] is called.